# some CSS stylesheet not linking to HTML

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with linking my css file to my HTML code. After looking at other people's issues I have tried renaming it stylesheet, move it into different directories and references from the root. I have commented out the bootstrap link, just to make sure if it is the stylesheet that is linking or if it was a stylistic order of preference, which it is not.

I just entered some random text into the body and tried manipulating it with color and font just to see if the css was linking which it is not. Any other advice about directory structure etc is also much appreciated.

The styling did work if I referenced style directly via style="..." in the HTML code. The bootstrap references also worked, its just this one file which doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>StopUnderThinking</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css_bootstrap/bootstrap.css">-->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css" href="../static/custom.css">
    <script src="../static/js_bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ... 
</body>
</html>
```

In custom.css, to see if anything changes, even when specifically targeted it doesn't work

```
* {
    color: blue;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}
```

an image of the directory structure:

[image: an image of the directory structure]

Answer (score 1):

Missing double quote in :

```
type=text/css"
```

Replace it by

```
type="text/css"
```

I think it should work

*By the way, the type is not required when you are calling your css file.*

Comment: ah thank you, i was being really stupid and spent two hours trying to fix that haha

Comment: I knew that too don't worry things like that appends ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>StopUnderThinking</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/custom.css">
    <script src="../static/js_bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

You had not added type="text/css" correctly
        ...

Answer (score 0):

```
type=text/css"
```

This is the problem. Mising this **"** (opaning double quote)

replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/custom.css">
```